# Is there some SSH server for android-x86?

Tags: ssh, android-x86

I am using Android ICS x86 build for debug purposes in VMware Workstation, but I can't find any ssh server, so how can I install ssh server on it? I've tried SSHDroid, Dropbear SSH and some others - all they doesn't work, because they request ARM architecture.

Comment: You are likely going to need OpenSSH, ported to ICS x86. Someone may already have tried this. See: http://www.openssh.org/

Comment: [Dropbear SSH](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) is FOSS. You should be able to generate a IA32 binary from the source and run it under android-x86.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at Servers Ultimate on Play. The SSH server itself works on all devices and command line works on ARM and x86.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate

Comment: Thanks! Servers Ultimate is the only SSH server that works for me on Android x86 emulator

Comment: Not working on my Android 5.1. Possibly due to 64-bit platform.